# Removing duplicates based on 3 columns in R

Tags: r, sorting, duplicates

I have a data set of 300k+ cases and where a customer id may be repeated several times. Each customer has a date and rank associated with it as well. I'd like to be able to keep only unique customer ids sorted first by date then if there is a duplicate id with a duplicate date it would sort by rank (keeping the rank closest to 1). An example of my data is like this:

```
Customer.ID  Date     Rank
576293     8/13/2012    2
576293     11/16/2015   6
581252     11/22/2013   4
581252     11/16/2011   6
581252     1/4/2016     5
581600     1/12/2015    3
581600     1/12/2015    2
582560     4/13/2016    1
591674     3/21/2012    6
586334     3/30/2014    1
```

Ideal outcome would then be like this:

```
Customer.ID  Date     Rank
576293     11/16/2015   6
581252     1/4/2016     5
581600     1/12/2015    2
582560     4/13/2016    1
591674     3/21/2012    6
586334     3/30/2014    1
```

Comment: Seems like you should just sort your data and then use `unique()` or `duplicated()` to get rid of duplicated IDs.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide sample data by `dput` function.

Comment: Your outcome do not have unique customer ids

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain the output for customer ids 576293 and 581252.

Comment: For 576293 I would like the most recent date to take precedent over rank. For 581252 I made an error in modeling the outcome. It's now been edited.

Comment: `df %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% group_by(Customer.ID) %>% arrange(desc(Date), Rank) %>% slice(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the desired output of the OP clarified:

We can also do this with base R, which will be faster than the below `dplyr` approach using `group_by(Customer.ID)` since we are not going to have to loop over all unique `Customer.ID`:

```
df <- df[order(-df$Customer.ID,as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"),-df$Rank, decreasing=TRUE),]
res <- df[!duplicated(df$Customer.ID),]
```

Notes:

1. First, sort by `Customer.ID` in ascending order followed by `Date` in descending order followed by `Rank` in ascending order.
2. Remove the duplicates in `Customer.ID` so that only the first row for each `Customer.ID` is kept.

The result using your posted data as a data frame `df` (without converting the `Date` column) in ascending order for `Customer.ID`:

```
print(res)
##   Customer.ID       Date Rank
##2       576293 11/16/2015    6
##5       581252   1/4/2016    5
##7       581600  1/12/2015    2
##8       582560  4/13/2016    1
##10      586334  3/30/2014    1
##9       591674  3/21/2012    6
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Customer.ID = c(591674L, 586334L, 582560L, 581600L, 
581252L, 576293L), Date = c("3/21/2012", "3/30/2014", "4/13/2016", 
"1/12/2015", "1/4/2016", "11/16/2015"), Rank = c(6L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("Customer.ID", "Date", "Rank"), row.names = c(9L, 
10L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 2L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

If you want to keep only the latest date (followed by lower rank) row for each  `Customer.ID`, you can do the following using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(Customer.ID) %>% arrange(desc(Date),Rank) %>% 
              summarise_all(funs(first)) %>%
              ungroup() %>% arrange(Customer.ID)
```

Notes:

1. `group_by` `Customer.ID` and sort using `arrange` by `Date` in descending order and `Rank` by ascending order.
2. `summarise_all` to keep only the first row from each `Customer.ID`.
3. Finally, `ungroup` and sort by `Customer.ID` to get your desired result.

Using your data as a data frame `df` with the `Date` column converted to the `Date` class:

```
print(res)
### A tibble: 7 x 3
##  Customer.ID       Date  Rank
##        <int>     <date> <int>
##1      576293 2015-11-16     6
##2      581252 2016-01-04     5
##3      581600 2015-01-12     2
##4      582560 2016-04-13     1
##5      586334 2014-03-30     1
##6      591674 2012-03-21     6
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Customer.ID = c(576293L, 576293L, 581252L, 581252L, 
581252L, 581600L, 581600L, 582560L, 591674L, 586334L), Date = structure(c(15565, 
16755, 16031, 15294, 16804, 16447, 16447, 16904, 15420, 16159
), class = "Date"), Rank = c(2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
6L, 1L)), .Names = c("Customer.ID", "Date", "Rank"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This got me there. The tricky part was that I needed date descending and rank ascending. Since I wasn't able to figure out how to sort multiple ways at a time, I recoded 'rank' in the opposite direction (so 1=6, 2=5, etc.)Then your code worked great. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Gorman: the code I posted should do that for you without having to recode `Rank` if `Rank` is `numeric`. This is because it uses `-df$Rank` with `decreasing=TRUE` in `order`. Note that we need to use `decreasing=TRUE` in `order` because `-as.Date(...)` will not work.